# Printing from sets and hashmaps

Tags: java

I am working on a Java app that takes in 2 text files, among other arguments, creates hashmaps for them and preforms a few comparative methods on them. One method prints all the unique words each files shares, prints these words and then calculates the Jaccard Index of the two files. I would also like this method to also print the counts of occurrence of each word in each file, and I was wondering what the best way to do that would be. I have looked through a number of other examples on here, but couldn't find an answer.

Below is part of the method I currently use. The two hashmaps contain only unique words, and counts for the frequency associated with each word. It provides the words each file has in common, but I would also like to see the frequency of each word used in each file.

```
public double compareMaps(HashMap<String,Integer> hMap1,HashMap<String,Integer> hMap2){

    Set<String> mapSet1 = new TreeSet<>(hMap1.keySet());
    Set<String> mapSet2 = new TreeSet<>(hMap2.keySet());

    Set<String> Intersect = new TreeSet<>(mapSet1);
    Intersect.retainAll(mapSet2);


    Set<String> union = new TreeSet<>(mapSet1);

    union.addAll(mapSet2);

    Iterator iterator;
    iterator = Intersect.iterator();
    System.out.printf("%nUnique words in Document 1: %d%nUnique words in Document 2: %d%n", hMap1.size(), hMap2.size());

    System.out.println("Word\t\tCount1\t\tCount2");
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

- My current output.
- Unique words in Document 1: 91
- Unique words in Document 2: 122
- Word      Count1      Count2
- a
- also
- an
- and
- What I would like:
- Unique words in Document 1: 91
- Unique words in Document 2: 122
- Word      Count1      Count2
- a               4               7
- also            3               3
- an              5               4
- and             3               6

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counts are in the original maps passed in, so you need to get them from there:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String word = iterator.next();
  System.out.println(word + "\t" + Integer.toString(hMap1.get(word)) + "\t" + Integer.toString(hMap2.get(word)));
}
```

Comment: No need for `Integer.toString` since string concatenation will convert the integers to strings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the occurrence of each work from a file you can use the following code:

```
//spit pattern sentences to words
static final Pattern SPLIT = Pattern.compile("[- .:,]+");

//read the file with Buffered reader. 
BufferedReader reader =  Files.newBufferedReader(
            Paths.get("<add_here_the_filename>), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//solution one - using group
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<String>>> solution_1 =
        reader.lines()
              .flatMap(line -> SPLIT_PATTERN.splitAsStream(line))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.substring(0,1),
                       Collectors.groupingBy(String::length)));
```

Alternatively you can use toMap() to create the map with the occurence of each word.